# Holding Sequence of Variables Constant

Tags: notation

I know that a zero subscript is a common way to notate a variable that is being held constant - e.g. $x_0$, as in $f(x_0, y)$. However, let's say we had a function of many variables, such as $$f(x_i, ..., x_n)$$ and we wanted to hold all variables **except** $x_i$ constant. Then, let's say we wanted hold all variables except for the second variable in the sequence constant. What is the best way to notate this for each variable in the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is to put a hat over the variable not being held constant ;
 like $f(x_1,x_2 \ldots \widehat{x}_j \ldots x_n)$ would mean that the $j$-th variable is not held constant ,for example $f$ may be linear in the $j$-th variable with the other's fixed for each $j$ ;this called multi-linear .

Comment: So, if you use the circumflex, putting the zero subscript would be unnecessary?

Comment: yes , that's exactly right

Comment: I just saw online that, in set notation, a circumflex above an element means that the element is removed from the set. Does this mean that, using your example, the entire set is held constant but the $j-$th variable is removed from the set?